# Allocating integers from sequence with transaction in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, transactions

I have some sequence in database, represented by range. It has three fields: beginId, nextId and endId.

The task is to acquire the nextId from this range, and to ensure that it is unique. The code could be ran in highly parallelized environment, with many threads, on many machines.

What I need to do:

```
lock(database)
{
    var seq = GetSequence()
    var acquiredId = seq.NextId;
    seq.NextId++
    Save(seq)
}
```

So I use this code:

```
using (ISession session = GetSessionFactory().OpenSession())
using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead))
{

    var sequence = session.CreateCriteria<Sequence>().Single(); // This line is simplified

    var allocatedId = sequence.NextId; 
    sequence.NextId++;

    session.SaveOrUpdate(sequence);
    transaction.Commit();
    return allocatedId;
}
```

But for some reason when I run this code in multi-threading for testing, I received the same id assigned several times. I'm using the transaction with RepeatableRead lock, but that doesn't help.

P.S. Id doesn't mean Id of the table - it just the name agreement we use.

Comment: Can you write which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Just FIY: there is no need to call `session.SaveOrUpdate(sequence);` because the sequence already from session and session will track changes automatically.

Comment: Also please read this Ayende's post about how to deal with concurrency in NH http://ayende.com/blog/3946/nhibernate-mapping-concurrency

Comment: @MonkeyCoder The application should work with MySQL and MsSQL. Any other is under the question, but of course it would be nice not to stick to any, or if stick - do that as little as possible. Currently I tried this approach on MySQL v5 - and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I've used .Lock().Upgrade when the data is taken from DB, and everything worked. Thanks to hazzik for the link.

Now my code have this:

```
session.QueryOver<Sequence>().Lock().Upgrade.DoSomeFiltering().Single()
```